# Get left hand side of hyphen from string in bash?

Tags: bash

So I'm expecting the user to input a string in like this: "something-5, something-2, something-3".

I got the string to comma separate with this:

```
IFS=',' read -a SLAVE_ARR <<< "$slaveAmounts"
```

where SLAVE_ARR is the new array and slaveAmounts is the string that's passed in.

However, I want to read in the left and right hand side of each of the comma separated values. How do I do that? so basically I want a command so I can save the left hand side in one variable and the right hand side in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use bash [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
[cnicutar@ariel ~]$ item=something-5
[cnicutar@ariel ~]$ echo ${item#*-}
5
[cnicutar@ariel ~]$ echo ${item%-*}
something
```

And do a `for item in ${SLAVE_ARR[*]}` to iterate over them.

Comment: Anywhere where I can learn more about bash string manipulation/delimiters?

Comment: @vsingal5 I linked a page on TLDP. There's also a great chapter on Cameron Newham's [*Learning the bash Shell: Unix Shell Programming*](http://www.amazon.ca/Learning-bash-Shell-Unix-Programming/dp/0596009658).